# Curly braces, equal sign and javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following sample tokens inside my HTML pages:

```
{#abc,def#}
```

Using javascript I need to extract text from these tokens, like this:

```
abc,def
```

I'm using this reg exp:

```
/(({#).*(?=#})) /g
```

but it matches two groups:

```
group1: {#test, date 
group2: {#
```

How can I change them to match correct groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> '{#abc,def#}'.match(/{#(.*?)#}/)[1]
'abc,def'
```

**UPDATE**

```
> var xs = '{#abc,def#} foobar {#ghi,jkl#}'.match(/{#(.*?)(?=#})/g);
> for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) xs[i] = xs[i].substr(2);
> xs
[ 'abc,def', 'ghi,jkl' ]
```

Or a one-liner:

```
var tokens = (str.match(/{#(.*?)(?=#})/g) || []).map(function(match)
{
    return match.substr(2);
});
console.log(tokens);//[ 'abc,def', 'ghi,jkl' ]
```

If you want to support all browsers/implementations, you might have to augment the array proptotype:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
    Array.prototype.map = function(callback)
    {
        if (typeof callback !== 'function')
        {
            throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        }
        for(var i = 0;i<this.length;i++)
        {
            this[i] = callback(this[i]);
        }
        return this.slice();
    };
}
```

Comment: This does fail with strings like `'{#abc,def#} foobar {#ghi,jkl#}'`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem how?

Comment: @m.buettner: in js there's no mutli-matching with groups. They need to resort to exec/replace to capture them all.

Comment: @m.buettner: because it fails to capture the second token (OP mentions _tokens_), and upon adding the global flag, the matches are `{#abc,def#}` and `{#ghi,jkl#}`

Comment: @thg435 oh right... well then `g` and `exec`... seeing the OP is using `g` I figured he was aware of that anyway

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I added another code that can match `'{#abc,def#} foobar {#ghi,jkl#}'`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, Not all javascript implementation have Array.map method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @falsetru: Added a basic map method, too, to add `.map` support